# Combine three SQL queries

Tags: sql, forum

I'm trying to fetch data for my forum's index. Fetching a list of all the boards, the number of threads in that board, and the number of posts for each of those threads in that board.

```
SELECT 
board.*, 
IFNULL(a.thread_count, 0) AS thread_count,
b.post_count

FROM 
(SELECT * FROM r_forum_boards ORDER BY position) board 

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT r_forum_threads.board, r_forum_threads.id, 
         COUNT(r_forum_threads.id) AS thread_count 
     FROM r_forum_threads) a 
ON board.id = a.board

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT r_forum_posts.thread_id, COUNT(*) AS post_count 
 FROM r_forum_posts) b
ON b.thread_id = a.id
```

The problem is that post_count is returning `NULL`. I've tried a few different variations of this, but none of them are working.

Comment: If you run each of the sub queries separately, do they all give results?

Comment: If I remove the last JOIN, it returns the correct results with the correct thread counts. And if I query the last JOIN it returns the correct post counts for each thread ID. I guess I need to find a way to SUM all of those results per board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing from the IFNULL that your SQL is MySQL-flavored.  In that case, you can use `COUNT DISTINCT` to simplify things.

```
SELECT 
board.id,
COUNT(DISTINCT r_forum_threads.id) AS thread_count,
COUNT(r_forum_posts.id) AS post_count
FROM board 
LEFT OUTER JOIN r_forum_threads ON board.id = r_forum_threads.board
LEFT OUTER JOIN r_forum_posts ON r_forum_posts.thread_id = r_forum_threads.id
GROUP BY board.id
ORDER BY board.position
```

Depending on how much of `board.*` you actually need, either add columns to the SELECT and GROUP or use this as a subquery to join back to `board`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in a GROUP clause:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT r_forum_threads.board, r_forum_threads.id, COUNT(r_forum_threads.id) AS thread_count FROM r_forum_threads GROUP BY r_forum_threads.id) a 
ON board.id = a.board

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT r_forum_posts.thread_id, COUNT(*) AS post_count FROM r_forum_posts GROUP BY r_forum_posts.thread_id) b ON b.thread_id = a.id
```

See if that does the trick.

Comment: The post count does not align to each board. The first board gets duplicated with the post counts from the other boards. Then the rest of the boards are returned with null post count.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because you are missing the Group By clause in your subqueries? In addition, you do not need the first subquery.

```
Select board...
    , Coalesce(a.thread_count, 0) AS thread_count
    , b.post_count
From r_forum_boards 
    Left Join   (   
                Select r_forum_threads.board
                    , r_forum_threads.id
                    , Count(r_forum_threads.id) AS thread_count 
                From r_forum_threads
                Group By r_forum_threads.board
                    , r_forum_threads.id
                ) a 
        On a.board = board.id

    Left Join   (
                Select r_forum_posts.thread_id
                    , Count(*) AS post_count 
                From r_forum_posts
                Group By r_forum_posts.thread_id
                ) As b
        On b.thread_id = a.id
Order By r_forum_boards.position
```

You might consider changing the query slightly to make it easier to test:

```
Select board...
    , Coalesce(a.thread_count, 0) AS thread_count
    , A.post_count
From r_forum_boards 
    Left Join   (   
                Select r_forum_threads.board
                    , r_forum_threads.id
                    , Count(r_forum_threads.id) AS thread_count 
                    , Posts.post_count
                From r_forum_threads
                    Left Join (
                                Select r_forum_posts.thread_id
                                    , Count(*) AS post_count 
                                From r_forum_posts
                                Group By r_forum_posts.thread_id
                                )  As Posts
                        On Posts.thread_id = r_forum_threads.Id
                Group By r_forum_threads.board
                    , r_forum_threads.id
                ) As A
    On A.board = board.id
    Order By r_forum_boards.position
```

In this way, you can run the single inner query and ensure you A. get results and B. get values for post_count.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that you're trying to get 2 related but slightly conflicting pieces of data, and probably 2 queries will get you what you need.

You first need a query to get the board names and the number of threads in each board.

```
  Select Board.*, GroupThread.threadCount
  FROM r_forum_boards Board 
  INNER JOIN (Select board_id, count(*) as threadCount from r_forum_threads group by board_id) GroupThread ON Board.board_id = GroupThread.board_id
```

Second, for each thread, you need the posts, which are calculated in basically the same way:

```
  Select Thread.*, GroupPosts.postCount
  FROM r_forum_threads Thread 
  INNER JOIN (Select thread_id, count(*) as postCount from r_forum_posts group by thread_id) GroupPosts ON Thread.board_id = GroupPosts.thread_id
```

In each of these cases, you look at the parent object, and count the children.